# The Name of a Polyhedron with 6 Quadrilateral Faces, 8 Vertices, and 12 Edges

Tags: geometry

(Don't say 'cube' or 'rectangular prism')

I'm looking for a generic name for polyhedra with 6 Faces, 8 Vertices, and 12 Edges where each face could be any quadrilateral shape: rectangle, rhombus, trapezoid, etc.

What is this called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the name [**cuboid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid).

Comment: Indeed you are correct. Thanks!